# Which is the most intuitive to perform Dynamic Monte Carlo calculations?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

I'm trying to find a (free is possible) code to perform Dynamic Monte Carlo calculations over chemistry systems. Which one is the most intuitive one?

Comment: What do you mean by "Dynamic" Monte Carlo? Dynamic generally suggests motion, e.g. molecular dynamics simulations. MC does not simulate motion, per se, but rather samples configurational space in a random way.

Comment: Dynamic or Kinetic Monte Carlo is a technique to perform out-of-equilibrium calculations using the basic ideas proposed by the "usual" MC approach.

Comment: Got it. I'm familiar with Kinetic MC, just never heard it referred to as Dynamic MC before.

Comment: In chemistry, dynamic Monte Carlo (DMC) is a Monte Carlo method, also called Kinetic Monte Carlo for modeling the dynamic behaviors of molecules  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Monte_Carlo_method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform Kinetic Monte Carlo for a chemical reaction system, you can use [ZACROS](http://www.e-lucid.com/i/software/material_modelling/Zacros.html). I am not sure what your system is? You should follow some good text book like "[Understanding Molecular Simulation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780122673511)" to identify the type of your problem and appropriate software for that. There are plenty of freely available code on the internet but they all are for some specific purpose, So basically it is your responsibility to choose the best available software that will suit your need.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! Thank you for your insight. I edited in some links, so people have an easier way of finding things. This is always very much appreciated. (In case of ZACROS you might find a japanese touch screen company.) Please make sure, that what I inserted is correct. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :) you have hyperlinked the right website.